# How to setup logarithmic axis for line chart in rails chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

Is there way to setup log axis using chartkick and default chart.js library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the axis options using 'library' option like this:

```
<%= line_chart data, {
    library: {
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    id: 'y-axis',
                      type: 'logarithmic'
                },]
        }
    }
} %>
```

For more options please consult with [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) docs.

Answer (score 1):

Due to deprecation of methods in `chart.js` (effective from version 4.3) the syntax has changed.

```
[...]
legend: "bottom", library: { scales: { y: { type: 'logarithmic' } } }
```

`legend` is an attribute handle by chartkick and can be applied directly.

the `yAxes` and `xAxes` or `rAxes` calls are no longer used. The `id` is not a requirement.  But the identification of the axis to which apply the option is.  It now feels more natural, IMHO.